# How to LINQ.FOREACH to access parent

Tags: c#, linq, foreach

Parcels is a List

each Parcel has Owners property which contains List

```
parcels.Where(p => !p.Owners.IsNullOrEmpty()).SelectMany(p => p.Owners)
                    .OrderByDescending(x => x.RecordingDate ?? x.SaleDate ?? x.DateEntered)
                    .ForEach(owner =>
                    { 
                    /* HERE I need to access to p which was a parent of this Owner */
                    }
```

Not sure how to rewrite it...

Comment: ...and I assume that `Owner` does not happen to have a `Parent` property?

Comment: wait, do you mean you need to access p which was a *child* of this Owner? You're already accessing parents in the 1st part of the query, so why would it be any different if there are more parents further up the heirarchy?

Comment: Owner does not have a Parent property... I do have flexibility to add it, so I might do that.  (p is not a child of the owner, p is the original parent...)

Comment: if an object of the type in collection `parcels.Owners` has parents, but no reference to them, then it can't be done. You need a reference. [at least it can't be done in any useful way - you could go through the entire collection of owner.parents and compare its children to what you got from the query here so far]

Comment: I started doing something like... .SelectMany(p => 
                    
                    p.Owners.Select(
                c => new { Owner = p.Owners, p.PropertyICareAbout }));   Seems very convoluted and probably supremely inefficient.  I should have clarified it, I only need one property from the parent for now...

Answer (score 3):

make an anonymous pair to iterate over.

```
 foreach(var pair in parcels
    .Where(p => p.Owners != null)
    .SelectMany(p => new { o = p.Owners, p })
    .OrderByDescending(x => x.o.RecordingDate ?? x.o.SaleDate ?? x.o.DateEntered)) {

    var owner = pair.o;
    var parcel = pair.p;

    // do stuff
 }
 // alternate syntax
 foreach(var pair in from p in parcels
                     where p.Owners != null
                     from o in p.Owners
                     orderby o.RecordingDate ?? o.SaleDate ?? o.DateEntered descending
                     select new { o, p }) {
     var owner  = pair.o;
     var parcel = pair.p;
     // do stuff
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to add the parcel to the item returned by `SelectMany`:

```
parcels
        .Where(p => !p.Owners.IsNullOrEmpty())
        .SelectMany(p => p.Owners.Select(o => new { Parcel = p, Owner = o }))
        .OrderByDescending(x => x.Owner.RecordingDate ?? x.Owner.SaleDate ?? x.Owner.DateEntered)
        .ForEach(item =>
        {
            Parcel p = item.Parcel;
            Owner o = item.Owner;
            ...
        }
```